# How to implement in jna a structure sizeof() with an union type

Tags: java, kotlin, jna, openvr

I updated the [jvm openvr binding](https://github.com/elect86/openvr) to the last [openvr](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) version, 1.0.5, but I am unsure about one thing.

In cpp, there is the `IVROverlay` class with this virtual [`SetOverlayIntersectionMask`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2830) function:

```
virtual EVROverlayError SetOverlayIntersectionMask(
             VROverlayHandle_t ulOverlayHandle, 
             VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_t *pMaskPrimitives, 
             uint32_t unNumMaskPrimitives, 
             uint32_t unPrimitiveSize = sizeof( VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_t ) ) = 0;
```

My doubts regards the last argument.

[`VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_t`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2522-L2526):

```
struct VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_t
{
    EVROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitiveType m_nPrimitiveType;
    VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t m_Primitive;
};
```

is a struct with a enum type and an union type variable, called [`VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2516-L2520):

```
typedef union
{
    IntersectionMaskRectangle_t m_Rectangle;
    IntersectionMaskCircle_t m_Circle;
} VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t;
```

Which is being implemented by the two classes right above, [`IntersectionMaskRectangle_t`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2500-L2506) and [`IntersectionMaskCircle_t`](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L2508-L2513)

Now, the enum translates to an `Int` but the latter? Since it should be a pointer, I guess it shall be `Pointer.SIZE`?

However this is my implementation, where [`VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t`](https://github.com/elect86/openvr/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/openvr.kt#L4600-L4604) is an abstract class:

```
abstract class VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t : Structure {

    constructor() : super()
    constructor(peer: Pointer) : super(peer)
}
```

Implemented in turn by the [two other classes](https://github.com/elect86/openvr/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/openvr.kt#L4549-L4597).

My [first guess](https://github.com/elect86/openvr/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/openvr.kt#L5433-L5435) is that `sizeof(VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_Data_t)` translates to `Int + Pointer.SIZE`

```
@JvmOverloads fun setOverlayIntersectionMask(
                ulOverlayHandle: VROverlayHandle_t,
                pMaskPrimitives: VROverlayIntersectionMaskPrimitive_t.ByReference, 
                unNumMaskPrimitives: Int, 
                unPrimitiveSize: Int = Int.BYTES + Pointer.SIZE)
```

Does my reasoning appear correct?

Comment: your words are extremely confusing ... whats that about `sizeof`- do you actually think that this keyword is some sort of data type?? Well, it isnt. Its a C/C++ **operator** and it will yield a result of type `size_t` - no pointers involved unless you want to retrieve the size of a specific pointer ... which is actually a good idea since even pointers can be of different sizes, depending on your architecture

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I modified, I hope is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain the size of a `Structure` (including `Union`) with the `size()` method.  In the case of unions, you'll get the size of the largest member.

You set the desired type of the union with `Union.setType()`.

Comment: How can I check/query which struct of the union is? Is there a way from jna?

Comment: That's implementation-specific.  Usually the union has a common "type" field in each member, or you can tell from the context in which it is used.